# Using streams in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to build an API in Nodejs that will stream the output of a query that is executed against a vertica DB.

The vertica db driver in Nodejs exposes unbuffered query interface that I'm using. For more details about that please see:
https://github.com/wvanbergen/node-vertica

Following is my code:

```
var vertica = require('vertica');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs = new Readable;

var conn = vertica.connect( {
    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'verticadb'    
});


var q = conn.query('select * from table');

q.on('row', function(row) {
    rs.push(row.join(',') + "\n");
});

q.on('end', function(status) {
    rs.push(null);
    rs.pipe(process.stdout);
    conn.disconnect();
});

q.on('error', function(err) {
    conn.disconnect();
});
```

It does return the appropriate output, but my understanding is that it actually buffers up the output of `row.join(',') + "\n"` and only pipes it out to stdout once all rows are read. My objective is to pipe each row out as soon as it is read. How should I modify my code to make it work ? You can replace the vertica "row" event with anything comparable.

### Addendum

I've managed to make it work using what is called "classic readable streams" based on the documentation found on: https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook.

The code for this:

```
var vertica = require('vertica');
var Stream = require('stream');
var stream = new Stream;
stream.readable = true;

var conn = vertica.connect( {
    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'verticadb'
});


var q = conn.query('select * from affiliate_manager_2');

q.on('row', function(row) {
    stream.emit('data', row.join(',') + "\n");
});

q.on('end', function(status) {
    stream.emit('end'); 
    conn.disconnect();
});

q.on('error', function(err) {
    conn.disconnect();
});

stream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

However it is the "old" way of doing it, and I would like to know how to do it using the "new way".

Comment: `end` is only emitted once, which is at the end of the query. You should be emitting on each row.

Comment: I understand that part, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Readable` is “abstract”. It’s looking for a function called `_read`, which is not defined on the default implementation. Without it, it just buffers every `push(chunk)` until it sees `push(null)`. That’s the behavior you’re seeing in your example.

To get the behavior you want, just add a `_read` function!

Here’s an example you can adapt to your database:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var stream = new Readable;

stream._read = function () {
  var query = …;
  query.on('row', function (row) {
    stream.push(JSON.stringify(row) + '\n');
  });
  query.on('end', function () {
    stream.push(null);
  });
  stream._read = function () {};
};

stream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

---

Further reading:

- http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable_1
- https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#creating-a-readable-stream